# Android+How to swipe activities between tabs?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I used the  "fixed tabs + swipe" navigation and I want to set Activities content and logic to each tab. I've been searching a lot, and didn't find any solution.

I have the following:

```
public class ManejadorTabs extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla0_manejador_tabs);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment; 
        switch(i){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
             fragment = new Fragment1();
             break;
        case 2:
             fragment = new Fragment2();
             break;
        default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
        }

        //set args if necessary
      //  Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        //fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Tab1";
        case 1:
            return "T2";
        case 2:
            return "T3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How do I "convert" my activities into fragments, in order to display them on each tab?
Please help!

Comment: you can start by looking at the docs for `Fragments` so you can understand them and then turn your `Activities` into `Fragments` http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @CommonsWare He wants to use Fragments. Don't be so brash. "How do I "convert" my activities into fragments?"

Comment: @edwoollard: I went by the subject line and first paragraph of the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal recipe to convert an activity into a fragment. Generally speaking, your `onCreate()` logic will tend to be converted into an `onCreateView()` method, where you return the UI (rather than call `setContentView()`). Other lifecycle methods (e.g., `onPause()`) should work as-is. How many changes there are to the rest of your activity will vary from "not much" to "perhaps a lot".

As Emmanuel notes, start with [the fragments documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), then feel free to return to StackOverflow when you have more detailed questions.

Note that the "fixed tabs + swipe" generated code will only display tabs in certain circumstances: phone-sized screens in portrait and tablet-sized screens in landscape. In other configurations, the tabs will be converted into a drop-down list. If this is not what you want, consider using `PagerTabStrip`, instead of action bar tabs, with your `ViewPager`.